# Синтаксические отношения в сложном предложении

Tags: синтаксис

Какие синтаксические отношения в предложении "Еще на вершинах гор догорал день, но в ущелье уже отовсюду смотрела ночь" - противительные или сопоставительные? Заренее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то союз "но" всегда оформляет противительные отношения, чем он и отличается от "а", "и", "да" и подобных.
Но дело-то в том, что согласно [академической грамматике](http://rusgram.narod.ru/3108-3135.html) (§3127 и далее) противительные отношения являются в этом случае частым случаем сопоставительных.
Поэтому хотелось бы понять, почему в вопросе одно противопоставляется (простите за каламбур ) другому.

Comment: Спасибо, я сама только что поняла, что противительные отношения - частный случай сопоставительных.